# How to get precise inserted row's auto_increment primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables below

```
create table Order(
   OrderId int primary key auto_increment,
   UserId int not null,
   OrderDate date not null,
   IsPaid boolean default false,
   (...Reference statement for UserId...)
);

create table OrderProduct(
   OrderId int not null,
   ProductName varcahr(1024) not null,
   constraint `fk_orderid_from_orderProduct`
   foreign key (OrderId) references Order(OrderId)
);
```

Table `Order` represents each order user made,
Table `OrderProduct` is List of product(s) which each Product contains.
As you see, Primary key OrderId on `Order` table is auto_increment.

What I want to do is like below,

1. Create Empty Order for user by `INSERT INTO Order SET UserId=1234, OrderDate="2019-10-11";`
2. And I can retrieve which number is used as Primary key for Inserted `Order`(Assigned by auto_increment) And assume that it is `2368`
3. Add product to order like,
   `INSERT INTO OrderProduct (OrderId, ProductName) VALUES (2368, "iPhone"), (2368, "Toy"), (2368, "Computer);`

The problem is how can I get exact `OrderId` from `Order` table which is automatically inserted by auto_increment. This is not a problem if there are only one session, and all query are processed sequentially. But regarding many user create their own order, it become a problem. (In this case, cropping inserted Order's id by MAX(OrderId) or LastIndex()(right?) is not always precise cause other user can insert another order into table (And it will increase `OrderId`)

I considered to use query like (`SELECT OrderId WHERE UserId="alex0123" and OrderDate="2019-10-11"`) But this is not the answer as you know. It can crop what I want to, but cannot be guaranteed to be precise and I think it is not right.

Also, I'm considering locking table while specific user's transaction. But it will cause performance problem. (While someone process their order, the other cannot do that)

Is there any way to handle this? Or is there any DB scheme or method to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a SQL statement inserts a value for a column with `auto_increment` property, the inserted value will be transferred to the client in the [server OK packet](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ok_packet/#fields).

Depending on the programming language this value can be retrieved by an API function, e.g.

- C: `mysql_insert_id()`
- Python: `cursor->lastrowid`
- PHP: `mysqli_insert_id()`

But you can retrieve this value also with a single SQL statement:

```
MariaDB [test]> create table mytable (orderid int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into mytable values (NULL);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Wow I already checked other answer, but this is really what I'm looking for. For me, I need to do more tasks before inserting into another tables. Thanks too.

Comment: @Gipyo.Choi you can change the answer you accepted if this answer is better for your needs. Just tick the green arrow on this answer instead.

Comment: @Gipyo.Choi no worries - it's important that the answer that best matches the question is accepted, that makes it more useful to other users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) as it is maintained per client (session). From the manual:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a *per-connection basis*. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column *by that client*.

So your `OrderProduct` query would become:

```
INSERT INTO OrderProduct (OrderId, ProductName) VALUES 
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), "iPhone"),
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), "Toy"), 
(LAST_INSERT_ID(), "Computer)
```

Comment: Does this disregard which User is logged in DB? I mean in case of all user logged into DB by same account. (I understand this way cause it says 'connection')

Comment: As long as the queries are *not* coming from exactly the same client (e.g. PHP, Java, MySQL Workbench etc.) then the values are maintained independently. So e.g. two separate PHP/Java/... processes would get different results.